# Difference between relational database and documented oriented queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I have been able to find information regarding the difference in the designs between relational and document but have not found information regarding the queries other than examples of the queries. From what I have picked up documented oriented nosql queries are more complex but I don't understand why that is the case. Can someone elaborate further and help me understand?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Estra, your question is a good one, but unfortunately Stack Overflow has a really strict idea of what type of questions they want on this site. They want specific programming problems, not general questions about concepts. You'll probably see this question closed, but don't take it personally.

Comment: Sure that's no problem. I felt lost when looking into it so I thought of trying on stackoverflow. I'll keep in mind to stick to programming related questions in the future.